# How to store previously selected li option using jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I have multiple unordered lists with li's in the form of a radio selection display format. When I choose a subsequent li within an ul, I should be able to store the previously selected li and be able to access the text in the h3 above the ul until the next li is selected and it should go on in a similar fashion. Which selector of jQuery should I use? Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Usecase 1

```
<h3>text1</h3>
<ul id="one">
<li>some text</li>
<li>some text</li>
<li>some text</li>
</ul>
<h3>text2</h3>
<ul id="two">
<li>some text</li>
<li>some text</li> --> I select this li first.
<li>some text</li>
</ul>
<h3>text3</h3>
<ul id="third">
<li>some text</li>
<li>some text</li>
<li>some text</li> -> Next I select this li - at this point I should be able to get the text "text2" of the previously selected li and store it in a variable say var 1.
</ul>
```

Usecase 2

```
<h3>text1</h3>
<ul id="one">
<li>some text</li>
<li>some text</li>
<li>some text</li>
</ul>
<h3>text2</h3>
<ul id="two">
<li>some text</li>
<li>some text</li> --> I select this li first.
<li>some text</li> --> Next I select this li - at this point I should be able to get the text "text2" of the previously selected li and store it in the same variable as above ie var 1.
</ul>
<h3>text3</h3>
<ul id="third">
<li>some text</li>
<li>some text</li>
<li>some text</li> 
</ul>
```

Comment: It would be a good idea to accept answers to more of your questions. Doing so will encourage others to help you with this and other questions.

Comment: Thanks guys for the overwhelming responses, I'm going to try each of the answers and let you know, so far I have tried prev and closest before posting this question but no luck yet as when I try to satisfy usecase 1, the usecase 2 does not work and vice versa.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use the data object from jQuery

```
var dataHolder = $('ul').first();

dataHolder.data('oldEle', {
    text: 'NAN',
    index: -1,
    parentClass: "NANClass"
});

$('li').click(function() {

    alert('prev: ' + dataHolder.data('oldEle').text + ' index of prev: ' + dataHolder.data('oldEle').index + ' in parent: ' + dataHolder.data('oldEle').parentClass);
    dataHolder.data('oldEle').text = $(this).text();
    dataHolder.data('oldEle').index = $(this).index();
    dataHolder.data('oldEle').parentClass = $(this).closest('ul').attr('id');
});
```

[data jquery example](http://jsfiddle.net/9PYN8/)

Comment: This piece of code rocks. Thanks zdrsh! Never used data function from jQuery before, but it does exactly what I wanted to achieve.

Answer (score 1):

Just store the last clicked item at the end of the click event. You can then work your way back up the dom to get the value of the relevant h3.

```
var lastClickedLi = null;
var var1 = "";
$('li').click(function() {
    if (lastClickedLi != null) {
        var1 = lastClickedLi.closest('ul').prev('h3').text();
    }
    lastClickedLi = $(this);
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6yypn/

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastClickedText;

$('li').live('click', function () {
    if (lastClickedText) {
        alert(lastClickedText);
    }
    lastClickedText = $(this).parents('h3').text();
});
```

this should alert whatever the inner text of the parent H3 of the last clicked LI was. Untested.

Comment: h3 is not a parent of li, its a sibling of its parent ul (of which there are multiple h3). I am not sure that this will work.

Comment: @RichardEdwards you are probably correct, jquery's .closest() may be a better choice.

Answer (score 0):

```
var lastLiH3;
$('li').click(function(){
    if(lastLiH3){
        alert(lastLiH3);
    }
    lastLiH3 = $(this).parent('ul').prev('h3').text();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you need?

http://jsfiddle.net/RZRcC/7/

html:

```
<h3>text1</h3>
<ul id="one">
    <li><input type="radio" value="test1" name="t1"/></li>
    <li><input type="radio" value="test1" name="t1"/></li>
    <li>v</li>
</ul>
<h3>text2</h3>
<ul id="two">
    <li><input type="radio" value="test1"  name="t2"/></li>
    <li><input type="radio" value="test1"  name="t2"/></li> --> I select this li first.
    <li><input type="radio" value="test1"/></li>
</ul>
<h3>text3</h3>
<ul id="third">
    <li><input type="radio" value="test1"  name="t3"/></li>
    <li><input type="radio" value="test1"  name="t3"/></li>
    <li><input type="radio" value="test1"  name="t3"/></li> -> Next I select this li - at this point I should be able to get the text "text2" of the previously selected li and store it in a variable say var 1.
</ul>
```

The jQuery part:

```
var lastSelect = null;
var lastSelectHead = null;
$(document).ready(

function() {
    $("li > input[type='radio']").click(

    function() {
        if (lastSelect) {
            lastSelectHead = $(lastSelect).parents("ul").prev("h3").text();
        }
        lastSelect = this;
        if (lastSelectHead) {
            alert(lastSelectHead);
        }
    });
});
```